# Why do I see "No applicable role project templates found" error?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

When trying to create a new Windows Azure Project in Visual Studio 2010, I get the error "No applicable role project templates found." Why? I can't find any info on this error.

Comment: Weird no one has run into this before. Turns out, in the New Project dialog, .NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1 was selected by default. Changed it to .NET Framework 4 and everything was fine.

Comment: Weird yes, in mine and coworkers case, it worked out of the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed that I experience this problem if the target framework is set to ".NET Framework 4 Platform Update 1 (KB2478063)". If I select ".NET Framework 4" as target framework, the problem disappears.

I believe it might ave something to do with the fact that the PU is not yet supported with Azure, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsazuredevelopment/thread/8f9ed9d9-0b1b-4f86-9448-2229fed5311d/

As of July 15, the Azure Guest OS supports the PU (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh321001.aspx), but I don't think the Azure SDK supports it yet.

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment above, selecting the **.Net Framework 4** as the target framework allows the role project templates to be found.